# How to find out current logged-in user in widget in Django Wagtail

Tags: django-forms, wagtail, django-widget, wagtail-admin

I have been looking for a way to find out who the current logged-in user is in Django Wagtail so that I could create a widget to render a base setting field to be editable/non-editable. I was able to get some basic logic working but couldn't figure out how to find who the current logged-in user is. Can someone help me find out what's the best and most secure way to go about this?

##### models.py

```
    @register_setting
    class AdminSetting(BaseSetting):
      ...
      permitted_retries = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=10)
      panels =[
         FieldPanel('permitted_retries', widget=PermittedRetriesWidget())
      ]
      base_form_class = AdminSettingForm
```

##### admin_setting_forms.py

```
 class AdminSettingForm(WagtailAdminPageForm):

    def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super(AdminSettingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['permitted_retries'].widget.user = 'me' # This goes to widget

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        return cleaned_data

    def save(self, commit=True):
        page = super().save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            page.save()
        return page
```

##### widgets.py

```
    class PermittedRetriesWidget(forms.Widget):
         ...
        def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
            if self.user.is_superuser:
               return format_html(f'<input type="hidden" name="{name}" value="{value}" id="id_{name}">')
            else:
               output = f'<div style="padding: 1.2em;">{value}</div>'
               input = f'<input type="hidden" name="{name}" value="{value}" id="id_{name}">'
               return format_html(output + input)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found another way to do this! This is probably better than ThreadLocal as I have been hearing so much bad things about it. I hope this will help someone out in the future.

##### panels.py

```
class RequestBoundFieldPanel(FieldPanel):
    def on_request_bound(self):
        if self.widget:
            setattr(self.widget, 'request', self.request)
```

#### models.py

```
from .panels import RequestBoundFieldPanel(FieldPanel):

@register_setting
class AdminSetting(BaseSetting):
  ...
  permitted_retries = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=10)
  panels =[
     RequestBoundFieldPanel('permitted_retries', widget=PermittedRetriesWidget())
  ]
  base_form_class = AdminSettingForm
```

##### admin_settings_form.py

```
 class AdminSettingForm(WagtailAdminPageForm):

    def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        is_superuser = self.fields['permitted_retries'].widget.request.user.is_superuser or False

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        return cleaned_data

    def save(self, commit=True):
        page = super().save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            page.save()
        return page
```

##### widgets.py

```
class PermittedRetriesWidget(forms.Widget):
     ...
    def __init__(self, attrs=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        is_superuser = self.request.user.is_superuser or False
        if is_superuser:
           # Shows the input as it is
           return format_html(f'<input type="number" name="{name}" value="{value}" id="id_{name}">')
        else:
           # Hide the input and show the value as uneditable 
           output = f'<div style="padding: 1.2em;">{value}</div>'
           input = f'<input type="hidden" name="{name}" value="{value}" id="id_{name}">'
           return format_html(output + input)
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out by using ThreadLocals, I think it's the easier and faster way.

##### middleware.py

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
import threading

_thread_locals = threading.local()


def get_current_request():
    return getattr(_thread_locals, 'request', None)


class ThreadLocals(MiddlewareMixin):
    """
    Middleware that gets various objects from the
    request object and saves them in thread local storage.
    """

    def process_request(self, request):
        _thread_locals.request = request
```

##### admin_settings_form.py

```
from app.contrib.middleware import get_current_request

 class AdminSettingForm(WagtailAdminPageForm):

    def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        current_user = current_request.user
        is_superuser = current_user.is_superuser or False
        self.fields['permitted_retries'].widget.is_superuser = is_superuser

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        return cleaned_data

    def save(self, commit=True):
        page = super().save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            page.save()
        return page
```

##### widgets.py

```
class PermittedRetriesWidget(forms.Widget):
     ...
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        is_superuser = self.is_superuser
        if is_superuser:
           # Shows the input as it is
           return format_html(f'<input type="number" name="{name}" value="{value}" id="id_{name}">')
        else:
           # Hide the input and show the value as uneditable 
           output = f'<div style="padding: 1.2em;">{value}</div>'
           input = f'<input type="hidden" name="{name}" value="{value}" id="id_{name}">'
           return format_html(output + input)
```